# How can I add a trait bound to a public type that refers to a private type?

Tags: rust, traits, type-bounds

I have a public generic type that wraps a private generic type. I'd like to state that my public type implements a trait whenever the private type does as well:

```
pub trait Example {}

pub struct PubliclyVisible<T>(Inner<T>);

impl<T> Example for PubliclyVisible<T> where Inner<T>: Example {}

struct Inner<T>(T);
impl<T> Example for Inner<T> {}
```

This generates an error because `Inner` is not public:

```
error[E0446]: private type `Inner<T>` in public interface
 --> src/lib.rs:5:1
  |
5 | impl<T> Example for PubliclyVisible<T> where Inner<T>: Example {}
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't leak private type
6 | 
7 | struct Inner<T>(T);
  | - `Inner<T>` declared as private
```

Is there some way of stating "`PubliclyVisible<T>` implements `Example` whenever `Inner<T>` implements `Example`" without requiring that `Inner` become public?